# Merge two data frames in R by variable that is regular expression in one and string in other

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I have two data frames I would like to merge

```
a<- data.frame(x=c(1,4,6,8,1,6,7,2),ID=c("132","14.","732","2..","132","14.","732","2.."),year=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

b<- data.frame(y=c(2,7,5,5,1,1,2,3),ID=c("132","144","732","290","132","144","732","290"),year=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

The ID Variable by which I would like to merge the two data frames is not completely known in data set a. I also want to merge by year. They are known up to a fully identifying regular expression. Note, there *is* a one-to-one match. In this example you would *not* find an ID "1.." in the data set so there are no ambiguous matches.

I would like to get something like this:

```
output<-data.frame(y=c(2,7,5,5,1,1,2,3),x=c(1,4,6,8,1,6,7,2),ID=c("132","144","732","290","132","144","732","290"), year=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

I tried to remove the regular expression part with substr and then use starts_with in the merge but it does not work.

I get the following error message

```
Coercing pattern to a plain character vector
```

when I do this:

```
df_complete <- regex_inner_join(b,a, by=c("ID","year"))
```

Thank you stack overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Comment by @jblood94

With `a` and `b` as `data.table`s: `a[, regex_inner_join(b[year == .BY], .SD, by = "ID"), year]` –
jblood94

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `fuzzyjoin` package, and then you can use the `regex_inner_join()` directly:

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(b,a, by="ID") %>% select(x,y,ID=ID.x)
```

Output:

```
  x y  ID
1 1 2 132
2 4 7 144
3 6 5 732
4 8 5 290
```

Comment: Dear Langtang. I sadly simplified the problem too much. There is a second variable by which I merge (year) and that does not allow the merge : Coercing `pattern` to a plain character vector when I do this:   df_complete <- regex_inner_join(b,a, 
                                     by=c("ID","year"))

Comment: @mclofa With `a` and `b` as `data.table`s: `a[, regex_inner_join(b[year == .BY], .SD, by = "ID"), year]`

Comment: nice, @jblood94!!